# Get text between tags in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm loading the website inside of an iFrame. I'm trying to get the text between `<carrier_name>` and `</carrier_name>` and display that inside of a textbox.

This is my HTML

```
 <iframe name="frameComp" class="frameComp" style="display:none" width="500" height="200"></iframe>
```

This is my javascript

```
 $('button[name="otherlistbut"]').click(function() {
     var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();
     $(".frameComp").fadeIn();
     window.open("https://api.data24-7.com/v/2.0?user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&api=C&p1=" + "1" + phonenum, "frameComp");

     var message = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
     message ==  $('.frameComp').contents().find("carrier_name").html();

});
```

This is the source code of the website

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
    <results>
        <result item="1">
            <status>OK</status>
            <number>13105555555</number>
            <wless>y</wless>
            <carrier_name>Verizon Wireless</carrier_name>
            <carrier_id>5</carrier_id>
            <country>United States</country>
        </result>
    </results>
</response>
```

Comment: Instead of loading the XML into an iframe, why don't you just download it via `$.ajax`?

Comment: @LeeTaylor no reason, would that be better? Why just it matter? I believe I read somewhere that I can't do that if the website is not on the same domain as mine

Comment: which value are you trying to get? Your question doesn't seem to state...

Comment: @LeeTaylor fixed formatting! I'm looking to get the value between `<carrier_name>` and `</carrier_name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$phonenum = $_POST["phonenum"];
$url = "http://api.data24-7.com/v/2.0?user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&api=C&p1=" . "1" . $phonenum;

$provhtml = file_get_contents($url);
$start_tag = '<carrier_name>';
$end_tag = '</carrier_name>';

$startpos = strpos($provhtml, $start_tag) + strlen($start_tag);
if ($startpos !== false) {
    $endpos = strpos($provhtml, $end_tag, $startpos);
    if ($endpos !== false) {
        $carrier = substr($provhtml, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
    }
}
echo json_encode($carrier);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, different approach...

```
$('button[name="otherlistbut"]').click(function() 
{
    var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();

    $('<iframe id="frameComp" src="https://api.data24-7.com/v/2.0?user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&api=C&p1=" + "1" + phonenum>').appendTo("body").ready(function()
    {
        // Wait until XML has actually loaded by testing if the required (known) element is there
        var interval = setInterval(function()
        {
            var carrier = $('#frameComp').contents().find("carrier_name")
            if(carrier.length > 0)
            {
                console.log(carrier.text());
                clearInterval(interval);
                $('#frameComp').remove(); // We no longer need the iframe...
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get an error in the console saying..."XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.data24-7.com/v/2.0?user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&api=C&p1=13105555555. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.WEBSITE.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Ah, I was aware that this may be an issue. I was however, expecting an API with credentials would perhaps allow this. Perhaps, then, loading in to an iframe may be the way to get around this. However, can you determine that the iframe way of loading the xml works?

Comment: Yeah it works, when I inspect element I can clearly see what I'm looking for

Comment: Okay so, I'm confused as to what I'm replacing. Do I leave my html framecomp? And where do I put the code you gave me =/?

Comment: Error message "  Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://WEBSITE.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://api.data24-7.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without access to the live XML file. I'd suggest using the `carrier` code, as this does work.

Comment: Here you go, I made an account real quick just to test.
http://api.data24-7.com/v/2.0?user=othertxt&pass=othertxt&api=C&p1=" + "1" + phonenum

Comment: I'm getting the same security issues trying to read the contents of the iframe. You'll either need to find a JSONP approach, or read the contents of the URL from server-side code (PHP, ASP, etc.) and then read that from $.ajax.  I'd be surprised if the api you're using doesn't allow for some workaround of CORS...

Comment: I changed `var carrier = $('#frameComp').contents().find("carrier_name")` to `var carrier = $('.body').contents().find("carrier_name")` and i gave my body tag a class of body. I'm currently getting no errors but nothing is showing up. When I view source of the whole website i can see the carrier_name tag

Comment: That won't work as it won't find the iframe... There's no way around it other than my suggestions as it's a browser security issue.